# What are the minimum jars needed for spring to be used in a standalone application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection, spring-3

him i am using **spring** in a **standalone application** for **Dependency injection**, **MessageSource** & **PropertyPlaceHolder** support, **Hibernate/JDBC** support,**unit testing**, and i was wondering what are the **minimum jars** needed for above requirements, and if i can exclude some jars or dependencies form my current configuration, since i don't need the application size to be big as it's a standalone application, i need to make the **application size** as **small** as i can, here's the dependencies i am using right now:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>  
            <version>${spring.version}</version>  

        </dependency>
```

**UPDATE:**

After minimizing the dependencies to:

1. spring-core.
2. spring-beans.
3. spring-context.
4. spring-context-support.
5. spring-expression.
6. spring-jdbc.
7. spring-orm.
8. hibernate-entitymanager.
9. validation-api.
10. hibernate-validator.
11. junit.
12. commons-logging.
13. slf4j-simple.
14. log4j.
15. derby.
16. cglib.

i still see some jars which i am not sure if they are important to my requirements or not:

1. activation-1.1.jar
2. antlr-2.7.6.jar
3. aopalliance-1.0.jar
4. asm-3.3.1.jar
5. commons-collections-3.1.jar
6. dom4j-1.6.1.jar
7. javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
8. jms-1.1.jar
9. mail-1.4.jar
10. spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
11. spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
12. spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
13. xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar

PLEASE advise if i should exclude some jars from them.

Comment: Since you're using Maven, why don't you list only your direct dependencies, and let Maven download the transitive dependencies for you?

Comment: i am sorry i am not that good in maven, can you please explain a little bit more what do you mean ?

Comment: Just list the dependencies that your code directly depends on (spring-jdbc, spring-orm, probably), and Maven will use the POM of these artefacts to determine the other artefacts needed (spring-code, spring-context, etc.). It will automatically download them and make them available in the classpath.

Comment: @JB Nizet did it, and i think that i still may be able to exclude some un-needed jars, please see my post update.

Comment: I don't understand: if you're listing the jars you directly use, and Maven is bringing in the required transitive dependencies, what are you really asking? Whether or not Maven works?

Comment: @Dave Newton, question is what do you think about the 13 jars i listed, are all of them important to DI,Hibernate/JDBC support,MessageSource can's i exclude some of them, to minimize the jars as much as i can

Comment: I think if Maven states that they're transitive dependencies, you eliminate them at your own peril--you would need to do a complete code path review based on your application in operation to know if they could be safely eliminated based on your particular use of the immediate dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that some of the transitive dependencies may be unused, but there is no automated way to determine this. You can exclude all transitive dependencies to start with (using excludes tag), build/run the app and keep adding appropriate dependencies, when you get an error. Some of them would fail compilation, others fail app at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core-tiger</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-struts</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
      </dependency>
```